# Using `on` to replace placeholders in Scala SQL query

Tags: sql, scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I'm trying to create a findBy method that takes in a key and value to search a table.  For some reason the following does not find anything:

```
def findBy(key: String, value: String): Option[Authentication] = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL("select * from authentications where {key}='{value}' limit 1")
    .on("key" -> key, "value" -> value).as(authentication.singleOpt)
}
```

But when I just use the plus sign, it does.  I wouldn't mind leaving it this way but there are benefits to being able to use `on`

```
def findBy(key: String, value: String): Option[Authentication] = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL("select * from authentications where " + key + "='" + value + "' limit 1")
    .as(authentication.singleOpt)
}
```

Example Query: `Authentication.findBy("email", "test@example.com")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play escapes the query parameters in prepared SQL statements. So you don't actually need to wrap `{value}` in single quotes. Unfortunately, this means the column names will be escaped with quotes as well by Play, so it'll be interpreted by the database as a string. I don't see a way around this without using string concatenation or string interpolation.

Scala string interpolation would look the code look a little better:

```
def findBy(key: String, value: String): Option[Authentication] = DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
    SQL(s"select * from authentications where `$key` = {value} limit 1")
       .as(authentication.singleOpt)
       .on("value" -> value).as(authentication.singleOpt)
}
```

Notice the "s" before the beginning of the string. The scala compiler will replace the token `$key` with the string `key` that's in scope. This should work, but `key` won't be escaped. So you'll have to sanitize the input for `key` yourself, unless you're using it internally only. Also, it's important to note that an input for `key` that isn't a column in the table will raise an `SQLException`.

Comment: This is interesting, however, the backticks don't work in sql and I can't get this particular method to work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The backticks work for me in MySQL, but perhaps your results may vary.

Comment: Ah I'm using postgresql, well thank you, that is very helpful.